# Is this a good wiring plan to replace a pool light switch with a wireless switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light, pool

I am trying to replace a pool light switch with a SURAIELEC wireless light switch and receiver kit. Please see the photo with wiring diagram. Am I right or wrong?

[image: please see the wires connection.]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you look in the  boxes or panels on each side of this box so you know exactly what you're dealing with. Take voltage readings at the switch because the line and load has to be accurate.

Comment: Is this in the US?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a bottom-of-the-barrel Cheese-pipeline-special module for this wireless switching job instead of something UL/CSA/ETL listed?

Answer (score 4):

It the hypothetical wiring scheme correct? 50% chance. We can't tell which black wire is line vs. load. But that should be easy enough to figure out. Whichever wire has power when the switch is off is the line wire and the other wire is load.

Neutral may be a problem here. You legitimately have neutral just looping through the box from one conduit (panel) to another (light). The problem is that in order to split it you need 6" on each end that will be in the box. If your wire has another 12" to spare, either in the panel (or previous location) or at the light fixture then you are OK. If you don't have that much to spare then you'll have to pull a new neutral for one part or the other, presumably whichever is a shorter run.

But the **BIG** problem is that the switch is junk. It has a big bold FCC listing and no indication of UL or ETL listing. That is classic for Chinese unapproved junk. The FCC listing (assuming it is legitimate) means that it won't cause too much radio frequency interference - which is actually a real concern with wireless switches. But it says nothing about safety. Plus there is no ground wire or ground screw, and it appears to be designed to mounted on a box knockout but with plastic instead of metal so that doesn't even take care of ground. **RETURN IT OR THROW IT AWAY.**

Then go ahead and buy a legitimate UL or ETL listed product. There are plenty, including major manufacturers such as Lutron, Leviton, TP Link/Kasa, etc. *Hint: If you find the a product (exact same manufacturer/model #) on both Amazon and Home Depot or Lowes then it is probably legitimate. If you find it only on Amazon and eBay then it is probably not.* I have nothing against cheap stuff - but for things connected to 120V electricity you really should stick to UL/ETL listed items for safety. The unlisted stuff *can* be safe but very, very often is not.

I also have nothing against Amazon. In fact, the more "Amazon" it is, the better. I found [this item](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YHBHP8T) which looks like it is either the same as OP's example or extremely similar. The key is that it says **Ships from Amazon** (which is great, you can get it quickly) but says **Sold by SURAIELEC**. There are a bunch of reasons why a product may be sold by a 3rd party rather than directly from Amazon. But if it ships from Amazon then that takes out the "we don't sell enough to stock it in the Amazon warehouse" and a bunch of other reasons. One of the big reasons to *not* be "Sold by Amazon" is that if it is sold by Amazon then Amazon will normally make sure that certain rules are followed as Amazon is then the importer of record for products produces outside the US. [TP Link Kasa - sold by Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HGW8N7R), [Lutron Caseta - sold by Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017LRCG38), etc.

Nothing inherently wrong with Amazon, just make sure you know what you are getting. Actually, [according to this report](https://www.forbes.com/sites/wadeshepard/2017/12/13/how-to-protect-your-family-from-dangerous-fakes-on-amazon-this-holiday-season/?sh=bc3b80d7cf18), there can even be issues when items are "Sold by Amazon", due to real and counterfeit products being mixed together, whether intentionally or not. So *always* check your products when you receive them from Amazon or any similar company to make sure you received what you ordered.

Comment: Thank you very much. A lot of knowledge info. I don’t understand why 2 red and green are in loop, nothing like 2 or 3 wires twisted together with wire nut. 
I have found out that which is line and load with multi-meter.  But I do not know that white is neutral. If it is neutral, can I add a pig tail?

Comment: How about this item

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/RunLessWire-Simple-Wireless-Light-Switch-Kit-No-Wires-and-Battery-Free-Light-Switches-for-Home-1-Receiver-and-1-Light-Switch-RW9-SKWH/317001312

Comment: Yes, that product is ETL listed, so it should be safe. White in conduit is **always** neutral. Yes, you should be able to pigtail, provided there is a few inches of slack. If not, you will need to pull a new neutral for one side or the other.

Comment: Considering that this is lighting (electrical) at a pool (water), making sure the switch is UL/ETL tested & approved is not only a good idea, it could be life saving.

Answer (score 2):

Advice: get a different switch.  This receiver is meant to go outside the junction box.  But it is not exterior rated so you can't mount it outdoors that way.  You can't put it inside your metal junction box because it then won't receive signals from the remote.

The remote is also not exterior rated so it will have to stay inside which is not ideal for a pool and likewise the signals won't reach the receiver because it's cheap.  And I bet that remote will kick the bucket the first time you pick it up with wet hands.

Unfortunately it's hard to find a smart switch that is exterior rated and will work in a metal junction box.  I hesitate to say "impossible" but I think you may need to find a way to change the switch location, maybe inside the house, in a plastic junction box, and to use a wifi or mesh (zwave, ZigBee) one that doesn't need line of sight to a proprietary remote.

Comment: I've got a couple of Shelly relays installed inside metal boxes in my house. Despite my crappy WiFi, I've had zero problems with them getting signal. These are indoors, not outdoors, so the "exterior rated" portion still applies, but quality switches/relays are available. +1 in general, though.